# PySpark: Use the primary key of a row as a seed for rand

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to use the rand function in PySpark to generate a column with random numbers. I would like the rand function to take in the primary key of the row as the seed so that the number is reproducible. However, when I run:

```
df.withColumn('rand_key', F.rand(F.col('primary_id')))
```

I get the error

> TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

How can I use the value in the row as my rand seed?

Comment: Wasn't able to get it working using expr. Instead I got "AnalysisException: u'Input argument to rand must be an integer, long or null literal.;'"

Comment: How are you using `expr`? What is the datatype of `primary_id`? Try `df.withColumn('rand_key', F.expr("rand(primary_id)"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with using `F.rand(seed)` function is that it takes long `seed` parameter and [treats it as literal](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/43763629f1d1a220cd91e2aed89152d065dfba24/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/randomExpressions.scala#L104) (static).

One way to go around this is to create your own `rand` function that would take column as parameter:

```
import random

def rand(seed):
   random.seed(seed)
   return random.random()

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

rand_udf = udf(rand, DoubleType())
df  = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (1, 'c')], ['a', 'b'])
df.withColumn('rr', rand_udf(df.a)).show()
+---+---+-------------------+
|  a|  b|                 rr|
+---+---+-------------------+
|  1|  a|0.13436424411240122|
|  2|  b| 0.9560342718892494|
|  1|  c|0.13436424411240122|
+---+---+-------------------+
```